# How can I match an input of not entirely digits?

Tags: java, regex

What is the proper expression for checking that any input contains at least one non-digit char?

```
"11111111"    doesn't match!
"1111111a"    match!
"1111 111"    match!
```

Comment: `(?:.*\D.*)+` ....

Comment: something like `[^0-9]+` ?

Comment: An opposite is shown here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6419262/string-contains-at-least-one-digit. Just use a negated character class.

Comment: @Amit why don't you prove yourself?

Comment: @PranavCBalan Please make an answer so that I can accept it. Don't be shy. Never mind the down votes.

Comment: @KevinEsche I'm sorry but I think it's not that simple.

Comment: a single `\D` would be enough

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Are you sure?

Comment: @JinKwon why not? If the input has one non-digit then of course it's not entirely consisting of digits and will match. Unless you want to consider each line is a separate input, or to match the whole line in the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regex where `\D` used for match any non-digit(`[^0-9]`) character.

```
.*\D.*
```

[Regex explanation here](https://regex101.com/r/iW2mT5/4)

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: What's the point of the "boilerplate" around the `\D`? If you don't use the "start of input" character (`^`), you'll get a match as long as a suitable charter is found.